# Copied particles.js config, but complete different results?

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

Vincent Garreau has an example of particles.js here
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

I basically copied his demo, but mine is creating huge circles and more connected lines, probably because of the huge circles.

Anyone familiar with the library and can help me out?

It's on this replit. I couldn't find another site that let me add a JSON file.
https://repl.it/@Kaleid/DependableConsciousPhysics

Comment: Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the plugin quite some time. Tried the config on the repo, and yes indeed it looks as you described. If you want to look like his screen shot, copy from the his CodePen instead **which is different** from his readme file.

After that I tried to set the `value` of `number` on `particle` object to 100. It would be something like this:

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 100,
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Notice that you must consider the number of particles to the size of its container so that I won't get full and causing fps drops.

Comment: It looks like the only difference in his codepen is that the particlesJS is passing the JSON config as the second parameter. I don't see why it wouldn't work, the way he demo'd. Maybe something with the pathing to the JSON file?

Comment: Figured it out, need to use particlesJS.load() if you loading a JSON file.